# Cannot Load Image Using Require In React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, image, api, react-native

I need to retrieve image from directory dynamically . and name of image comes from database via api. if i hardcode an online image it works fine but doesn't shows up any image when i retrieve data  from db instead it shows me error saying " Uncaught (in promise) Error: DeltaPatcher should receive a base Bundle when being initialized " here is my code.

```
const image = require("../Images/" + U_dp);

 return(
  <CardItem>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={require("../Images/" + U_dp)} />
            <Body>
              <Text>{U_name}</Text>
              <Text note>{agotime}</Text>
            </Body>
          </Left>
  </CardItem>
)
```

Comment: got this 'react native error: deltapatcher should receive a base bundle when being initialized' in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [React Native v0.59](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources):

> the image name in `require` has to be known statically.

That means, if you pass a variable to image path in `require`, it is not a static path, hence there is no way for React Native to render it properly.

From your question:

> I need to retrieve image from directory dynamically . and name of
>   image comes from database via api.

Since `U_dp` value is retrieved from api, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const image = require(`../Images/${U_dp}`);

 return(
  <CardItem>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={image} />
            <Body>
              <Text>{U_name}</Text>
              <Text note>{agotime}</Text>
            </Body>
          </Left>
  </CardItem>
```

I think this can help you. I replace this `<Thumbnail source={require("../Images/" + U_dp)} />`  with  `<Thumbnail source={image} />`. also i change your image const to

```
const image = require(`../Images/${U_dp}`);
```

hopefully, this can help you